# How to apply Rs. symbol in jasper report using currency code

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to display Indian Rs. symbol in my jasper report but i am not able to find any specific pattern which will generate that symbol in my reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your report Locale to Default - English (India)then your pattern in Currency will show Rs Symbol.

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to view in IE. is there any specific configuration require for IE?